# Sonos Music API getDeviceAuthToken retry responses not working

Tags: sonos

We've registered our service on the [customsd page](https://musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=node/134), and we're able to select it from the `Add Music Services` menu option. However, we're running into some difficulty during authorization.

When we start the sign in process, Sonos makes a `getAppLink` request to our service, we respond, and the button successfully takes the user to our sign-in page. That piece appears to be working.

However, we're running into issues with the `getDeviceAuthToken` polling that Sonos is doing. Once the sign-in process starts, Sonos consistently sends three `getDeviceAuthToken` requests and then gives up, sending no more requests even though we give back the necessary retry responses.

The requests from Sonos look like this (with some information partially or fully redacted and formatting added to the body for readability):

```
POST <our_soap_endpoint> HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US
Host: <our_site>
Max-Forwards: 10
User-Agent: Linux UPnP/1.0 Sonos/51.1-67300 (ICRU_iPhone11,8)
X-Sonos-Controller-ID: 02A4****
X-Sonos-Api-Key: 4348****
X-Sonos-Corr-Id: 0b99****
SOAPACTION: "http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1#getDeviceAuthToken"
X-FORWARDED-PROTO: https
X-FORWARDED-PORT: 443
X-ORIGINAL-HOST: <our_site>
X-Original-URL: <our_soap_endpoint>
X-Forwarded-For: <some_ip_address>
X-ARR-SSL: 2048|256|C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA|C=US, S=Ohio, L=Cleveland, O="OverDrive, Inc.", OU=OverDrive IT, CN=*.overdrive.com
X-ARR-LOG-ID: 5188****
Content-Length: 548

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceId>78****</deviceId>
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
        </credentials>
        <context xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <timeZone>-4:00</timeZone>
        </context>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <getDeviceAuthToken xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <householdId>Sonos_sIGu****</householdId>
            <linkCode>ab76****</linkCode>
        </getDeviceAuthToken>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Our responses look like this (again with some information partially or fully redacted and formatting added to the body for readability):

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2019 13:25:25 GMT

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>Client.NOT_LINKED_RETRY</faultcode>
            <faultstring>No token found for link code ab76****. Please retry.</faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

From what we can tell based on the documentation for [getDeviceAuthToken](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/sonos-music-api/getdeviceauthtoken/) and [error handling / faults](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/error-handling/), our responses appear to match what's expected for telling Sonos to try again. Are we missing something or doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Your response does not look correct. It should be something like this:

```
. . .
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>Client.NOT_LINKED_FAILURE</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Access to token failed</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns:ExceptionInfo>Restart authentication.</ns:ExceptionInfo>
            <ns:SonosError>6</ns:SonosError>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

See [HANDLING ERRORS DURING AUTHENTICATION](https://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/428) for details.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm feeling a bit confused on what exactly is wrong. I only see a few differences:
• We're using `s` as a namespace identifier, but I don't think that matters? 
• We're sending back a `Client.NOT_LINKED_RETRY` code. But the [Implementing Authentication page](https://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/405) seems to indicate that's what we're supposed to do unless authentication has definitively failed. 
• We're not including a `<detail>` element. But this [Error Handling page](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/error-handling/) says it's optional.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the namespace identifier can be anything you specify. However, handling errors during authentication is different from handling errors in other cases.    Please follow the steps under "RETRY RESPONSE TO GETDEVICEAUTHTOKEN" on the [Starting an implementation using browser authentication](https://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/405) page, including the `<detail>` element with the proper `<SonosError>` code. Let me know if this is successful as I'll update my answer above.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. Adding the `<detail>` element with the `<SonosError>` code seemed to get things working.